# Kendo UI Column Chart with Sparse Data displays incorrectly

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-dataviz

I am using KendoUI to display a column chart, but when I have sparse data (there is not a data point for every single category/series combination), the charts are completely wrong. I am hoping I am just doing something wrong!

Take the following data:

```
Category   Series   Value
---------------------------
1          Foo      10
2          Foo      12
2          Bar      9
```

I would like to create a chart where:

- the series are grouped, and keys are in the legend
- the categories are displayed along the x-axis, sorted ascending
- the values are the height of the columns

If I generate the chart, I get the following result:
[image: Incorrect chart result with sparse data]

There are several things wrong with this chart:

1. The column for the third data point (2, Bar, **9**) displays in the first column in orange - should be in the second column
2. The axis label for category 2 is displayed first - should be second
3. There is no axis label for category 1

However, if I add a 4th data point to my data source, the data displays correctly:

```
Category   Series   Value
---------------------------
1          Foo      10
2          Foo      12
2          Bar      9
1          Bar      7
```

[image: Correct chart result with non-sparse data]

I have a JS fiddle that illustrates the problem at http://jsfiddle.net/blackstarzes/eep2tn2g/1/

For completeness, the code I have:

HTML

```
<div id="chart"></div>
```

JS

```
var dr = [
    {
        "Category": "1",
        "Series": "Foo",
        "Value": 10
    },
    {
        "Category": "2",
        "Series": "Foo",
        "Value": 12
    },
    {
        "Category": "2",
        "Series": "Bar",
        "Value": 9
    },
];

    //Uncomment the following line to see the correct data
    //dr.push({"Category": "1", "Series": "Bar", "Value": 7});

var ds = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data: dr,
    group: { field: "Series"},
    sort: [{field: "Category", dir: "asc"}]

})

$("#chart").kendoChart({
    dataSource: ds,
    seriesDefaults: {
        type: 'column',
        labels: {
            visible: true,
            template: "#=kendo.format('{0:0}', value)#"
        }
    },
    legend: {
        visible: true,
        position: "bottom"
    },
    series: [{
        field: "Value"}],
    categoryAxis: {
        field: "Category"
    },
    tooltip: {
        visible: true,
        template: "#= dataItem.Series # #= dataItem.Category # #= dataItem.Value #"
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Are you in a position to add null values for points where no value exists:  http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/eep2tn2g/2/ ?

Comment: I could do that, but it's messy. That's what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: I ended up adding null points to the data source. Not a very nice solution, but it got the job done!